Как переводить дробное число в двоичной системе счисления (мантисса)?
bn = "101101.101"
ip, fp = bn.split(".")
d = int(ip, 2)
f = sum(int(digit) * (2 ** -(index + 1)) for index, digit in enumerate(fp))
num = d + f
print(num)

как можно упростить этот код для перевода дробной части

Что именно вы хотите тут упростить? Код делает буквально то что нужно, дробная часть обрабатывается в одну строчку, не вижу каких-то явных проблем.

Цикл не нужен
f = int(fp, 2) / 2**len(fp)

Кроме того, если дробная часть сама по себе отдельно не нужна, то можно запомнить позицию точки, удалить её, перевести всё целиком один раз в число и разделить на степень двойки. Проще это выглядит или нет - ХЗ... (Проверку на наличие точки не делал)
bn = "101101.01101"
po = bn.index(".")
bn1 = bn[:po] + bn[po+1:]
num = int(bn1, 2) / 2**(len(bn1)-po)
print(num)


Была у меня тоже такая мысль, но как-то я её не додумал )

@FilortBS Если ответ помог, не забывайте про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
